# MissingMethodException in Integration test with sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, mstest

I have the following exception:
[image]

I was using .NET 6 (I still had the error) and thought that it could be some conflict with the nugets I am using in my solution. It turns out that even after updating to .NET 7 the error persists when I run the test. For testing I'm using MSTest Framework and using an inmemory database (sqlite) to make integration tests. The error is happening when executing the line  `await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();`. The test classes are the following:

```
public class SQLiteDatabaseContextFactory : IDisposable
{
    private DbConnection _connection;

    private DbContextOptions<DataContext> CreateOptions()
    {
        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
            .UseSqlite(_connection).Options;
    }

    public DataContext CreateContext()
    {
        if (_connection == null)
        {
            _connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
            _connection.Open();

            var options = CreateOptions();
            using var context = new DataContext(options);
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        return new DataContext(CreateOptions());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
            _connection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
[TestClass]
public class SQLiteIntegrationTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMethod_UsingSqliteInMemoryProvider_Success()
    {
        using var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>()
            .UseSqlite(connection) // Set the connection explicitly, so it won't be closed automatically by EF
            .Options;

        // Create the dabase schema
        // You can use MigrateAsync if you use Migrations
        using (var context = new DataContext(options))
        {
            //await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
            await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
        } // The connection is not closed, so the database still exists

        using (var context = new DataContext(options))
        {
            var user = new ManualClassifier()
            {
                FirstName = "First",
                LastName = "Last",
                Email = "example@gmail.com",
                Username = "firstlast123",
                PasswordHash = "5994471abb01112afcc18159f6cc74b4f511b99806da59b3caf",
                PasswordSalt = "5994471abb01112afcc18159f6cc74b4f511b99806da59b3caf"

            };
            context.ManualClassifiers.Add(user);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        using (var context = new DataContext(options))
        {
            var count = await context.ManualClassifiers.CountAsync();
            Assert.AreEqual(1, count);

            var u = await context.ManualClassifiers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user => user.Email == "example@gmail.com");
            Assert.IsNotNull(u);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The full error is the following:
[image]

The .csproj of the project where I'm running the tests:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\VSC.Repo\VSC.Repo.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Dbcontext class library .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Services\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.2">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.2">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any help figuring what is happening would be much appreciated. I honestly have no clue what is causing this.

Comment: Can you please post full error text?

Comment: Of course, I will edit the post.

Comment: Can you please add .csproj file too? At least part with packages.

Comment: Yes, will do right away.

Comment: And the project with the db context?

Comment: Added the csproj of the assembly with DBContext. I will try to update to the latest version and will give you feedback.

Comment: It seems that my guess in the answer should be on the money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a lot like package version mismatch (in my practice it is the most common source of such errors). Update [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite) to the latest 7th version (my guess is that EF project uses that version) to match major version of EF Core packages in the tested solution.

Comment: This was exactly the issue. The test just passed! Thank you very much @Guru Stron!